# Traveling to USA to get a cheaper flight

Tags: air-travel, b1-b2-visas

I'm planning to go to Germany next year. A direct flight from my home country (Dominican Republic) would be about USD $1400. I have B1/B2 US visa and I was wondering if it'd be possible for me to purchase a round-trip flight from DR to Miami and then a second round-trip flight from Miami to Frankfurt. That'd save me up to $500 dollars, which is a considerable amount. I'd like to know if there'd be any issues with me entering the U.S twice in such a short period of time (around 10 days).

Comment: All things being equal, you should be fine and I would do the same and have done similar in the past. However note that IF you are unfortunate and for some reason you are not allowed into the USA, it will cost you more than $500 to change or buy new tickets. Being allowed entry into the USA is not guaranteed.

Comment: Fair point @SheikPaulofOsawatomie, I'm hoping I'm not denied entry, as I have never had any issues in the past. But who knows, right? Specially now that's "a different time, a different king...". Thanks for your input ^_^

Comment: For what it's worth, it is extremely common for Canadians to cross into the U.S. to fly out of Buffalo, Detroit, and so on for cheaper flights. It's the life blood of some tiny airports like BLI, PBG, or IAG. Ogdensburg, New York, population 11,128 at the last census— but only an hour from Ottawa— has English and French pages [for Canadian travelers](http://ogsair.com/Canadian/) and daily nonstops to Orlando. Of course, it's a lot easier for Canadians to enter the U.S. than just about anyone else.

Comment: @choster And at least as common for Canadians to take connecting flights through US airports to third countries (especially South America, but Asia as well), which still involves passing US customs. Personally I'd rather pay a reasonable difference and avoid the US unless I actually intend to visit there. Though I must say the US officials have been unusually polite the last couple times (the TSA not so much). At $500 USD I'd say it's worth the potential hassles depending on what you're planning on bringing with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you will not have any issue. I can say because my experience. I have been in US during February and I leave in February 15th. So, I traveled again to US 2 weeks after and I did not have any problem. Also, I do not think that they will make difference if you buy a Round-Trip from DR to Frankfurt or if you buy two Round-Trips. We know that there are a bunch of flights to Canada that there are legs in US.
It is important to know your situation, if they ask you and you need to know how to explain it.

Comment: All right, thanks! The round trip DR - Frankfurt actually connects through Miami, so I figured it wouldn't be much of an issue since I'd still need a valid visa to enter the US to catch my flights to Frankfurt/DR, even if I purchase them separately. Thanks again Marcel!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this but if your first flight is delayed you can run into serious problems, since it's not a single booking. Re-booking your second flight on the same day could be quite expensive.

I think your $1400,- number is too high. Consider alternative options using budget carriers. In Spring 2018

- Eurowings offers Puerto Plata<->Cologne round trips for as little as
  $600,-
- Air Berlin has Punta Cana <->Dusseldorf for about $1000,-.
- Condor offers Punta Cana <-> Frankfurt for about $820,-

  Added benefits: these are non-stops.

Disclaimer: these don't go every single day, so a bit of date flexibility will help. Some of these can also be combined with other cities in Germany. Air Berlin will take you to Berlin (from DUS) for only a few bucks more.

Comment: Are those prices for trips starting in Dominican?

Comment: @DJClayworth: Yes, all prices were checked with starting from Dominican

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar! I've been using momondo to try and track the cheapest flights, have not bumped into any of these flights you are showing. Maybe it has to do with the date..? I'm planning on visiting on Summer 2018 (there's this summit I want to attend to), so maybe that's why..? If you'd point me to any other search-engine as momondo I'd be greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea: for most airlines and websites it's too early to book for summer 2018. Most airlines will only book 11 or 12 months out. I would try again after summer 2017. http://www.flightconnections.com/ can quickly tell you what connections exist and who flies them. Then you can check the airlines website directly or sue something like www.hipmunk.com for specfic routes or adioso.com for flexible dates or flights into specific regions

Comment: Thanks again @Hilmar. I'm aware it's too early to check for summer 2018 flights, I was just basing it on checking it for this year on the same time-span. I also read somewhere (cant recall where) that late July - August its like the high season in europe, so prices are expected to be higher.