# How often can I visit the US on a B2 Visa?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I would like to visit the US for 5 days before making a trip to Guatemala for 1 month.
After my time in Guatemala I would then like to return to the US for 1 month to visit family before returning to work and family in my home country.
Is this allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traveling to USA to get a cheaper flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93126/traveling-to-usa-to-get-a-cheaper-flight)

Answer (score 3):

There's no law or regulation prohibiting this.  Each time you enter, however, you have to convince the border officer that you are a genuine visitor.  Two visits with a combined duration of about five weeks isn't likely to come close to being problematic in this regard unless you are stretching yourself financially.

Comment: And you have good reasons (if you are not a Latin American). Additionally, having just 5 days on first trip helps.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, you need to have a reason to travel in this frequency.  I have been in US in begin of January for a business travel and I traveled again in the end of January as vacation. So, I traveled again to US 2 weeks after and I did not have any problem.