# Will there be a problem making several trips to the USA with just days between them?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens

I have a family holiday booked to Florida and now a friend wants me to go with her as well, she is disabled so needs my help. It will mean that I will only be back in the U.K. for four days between trips. The first one is for 10 days and the second for two weeks.

Am I likely to have a problem when I arrive for the second trip?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How often can I visit the US on a B2 Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110028/how-often-can-i-visit-the-us-on-a-b2-visa)

Comment: @MarcelP. It's not a duplicate because this would presumably be under VWP. Even if the answer is the same, the question is different.

Comment: @MJeffryes, I agree. On the other hand, I believe the rule does not change. You need a reason.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in another answer, you need to have a reason to travel in this frequency. I have been in US in begin of January for a business travel and I traveled again in the end of January as vacation. So, I traveled again to US 2 weeks after and I did not have any problem.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the reasons given in the question are perfectly good reasons for a pair of closely-spaced short trips to the US. Especially since the total time in the US will be less than one month, this is incredibly unlikely to cause any kind of problem.